# Which field type should I use for a telephone number, and how can I ensure each entry is unique?

Tags: entities

I have created a field (field_telephone) to store telephone numbers like 13712345678.

Which is the best field type to use?
I also want to make sure the values for this field are unique. How can I do that?

Comment: You might want to try that again...

Comment: This...makes..no..sense.

Comment: I've had a go at cleaning up your question (and answered it based on that). If the edits are wrong please don't just rollback the edit, have another go at writing it. It wasn't comprehensible in it's original state :)

Answer (score 2):

For a basic telephone field without validation you could just use a text field, and set the maximum length to something sensible for telephone numbers in the regions you're targeting.

If you want a more advanced telephone field, check out the [Phone module](http://drupal.org/project/phone). There's a stable release for Drupal 6, but only a dev release for Drupal 7.

To make sure fields are unique, you can use the [Unique Field module](http://drupal.org/project/unique_field).

Comment: I also suggest you to try Phone Number module (http://drupal.org/project/cck_phone) which is similar to the phone module.